# Add '-' between specific text - Batch file windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, csv, command-line

I have like 30.000 lines like this one:

```
23 DE ENERO 23 DE ENERO
23 DE ENERO AGUA SALUD
```

After ENERO (1st one) i need to add a line like '-' So it'll look like:

```
23 DE ENERO - 23 DE ENERO
23 DE ENERO - AGUA SALUD
```

How can i do this with a batch file on windows?

Or there is a better approach in another language to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason you need to do this in a batch file?  *ie* is this for an automated process?  What is stopping you from using Find/Replace in a text editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
(
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q24276927.txt) DO (
  SET "line=%%a"
  SET /a start=-1
  CALL :split
 )
)>newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF

:split
SET /a start+=1
IF "!line:~%start%,5!" neq "ENERO" GOTO split
ECHO(!line:~0,%start%!ENERO - %line:*ENERO=%
GOTO :eof
```

I used a file named `q24276927.txt` containing your data for my testing.
Produces newfile.txt

Answer (score 3):

The Batch file below assume that:

- There are just one or two "ENERO" words per line, and
- The second one, if any, is at the end of the line.

That is, like in your example data! If the real data is different, this method needs to be adjusted accordingly.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

(for /F "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do (
   set "line=%%a"
   echo !line:ENERO =ENERO - !
)) > output.txt
```